# If $X \sim {\rm Binomial}(N,p)$, what is the distribution of $X/N$?

Tags: probability, distributions

Basically, I want to know the distribution of the realized frequency of a binomial model. I know this question has probably been asked many times, but I don't know how to search the answer to it.

Comment: Are you asking for the sampling distribution of the mean of a binomial?

Comment: No. I'm asking about the distribution of a binomial random variable divided by a constant (N is a special case)

Comment: Hint: $X = k \iff \frac Xn = k/n$.

Comment: Are you asking for the name of it or for how to write the pmf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a little bit to the hint above:
$$
P(X=k) = P(X/n = k/n).
$$